# Day extension - moment js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

There is a service that opens and closes on the days of the week (for example: Mon from 22:00 - 01:20, Tue: from 04:00 - 13:00, Wed: from 17:00 - 21:00 ...). At the moment my code works so let's say today is Monday and the time is 23:58 - the service is running .. the time is 00:00 the service is not working and will open at 04:00 .. (the time from 00:00 to 01:20 is not fixed because the day It's already Tuesday and the date is changing). I need some kind of flag solution that will not switch the day and keep the service open until 01:20 and close until 04:00

[console data - startTime - endTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJjO4.png)

[time settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRiA3.png)

```
        let startTime = moment(foundScheduleItem.open_at, 'HH:mm')
        let endTime = moment(foundScheduleItem.close_at, 'HH:mm')

        const afterStart = moment().isSameOrAfter(startTime)
        const isToday = afterStart && moment().isSameOrAfter(moment('00:00', 'HH:mm'))
        const beforeClose = moment().isSameOrBefore(endTime)

        if (service.extended) { //  extended - флаг
            const checkTodayBeforeMidnight = isToday && afterStart; 

            // If more than 00:00 but less than close time we dont add the day
            if (!beforeClose && checkTodayBeforeMidnight) {
                endTime = moment('23:59', 'HH:mm'); // no work
             } else {
                startTime = moment('00:00', 'HH:mm');
             }
        }
```

Comment: Are you creating the open_at and close_at times for this? Because rather than trying to fix this issue, I'd work on more accurate data. The service isn't open from Monday 22:00 until Monday 1:20, it's open from Monday 22:00 until Tuesday 1:20. If your open_at and close_at times are accurate then it should work. If you need to keep track of the current day, then just get the day for the startTime, and make sure the current time is before then endTime. If the current time is before the endTime, then the day you want is whatever day the start time equals.

Comment: Also, welcome to stackoverflow, can you please share your logic for turning the service on and off? At the moment I just see the times, but not how you're using them

Comment: @BrettEast edit description, please look again

Comment: Got it, are you building the time settings interface as well? That's where I would focus my time, because there is an error in there you're allowing the closing time to be before the opening time. I would instead do a check and if the closing time is before the opening time, then move it to the next day - or allow the option to specify the day for the closing time